# How do you safely upgrade an EC2 Einstance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html#change-instance-type-of-ebs-backed-instance

Read the above and it seems straightforward. Basically, need to backup the volume and then create a new EC2 instance and then take the volume and attach it, and then assign the old IP after unassigning it.

> Install your application and any required software on the new instance.
>
> Restore any data that you backed up from the instance store volumes of the original instance.

The issue are these two steps. Why would I need to install any new application if I take the volume of the old server? If I need to reinstall everything, then this option would be bad for me. I recall having tried something similar for a staging server and I think it didn't work at all. It is most probably because I had to reinstall everything.

So, is changing the instance type of the already existing instance the best option. What if it doesn't start? Would switching back to the old instance type solve the problem immediately? I am trying to predict everything that can go wrong.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? When you say 'upgrade' do you mean increase size, or update the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to change the instance type, just stop it and change the instance type. Backup first if you're cautious. The link you posted says just that.

If you wish to upgrade the OS, just log in and do the upgrade as you normally would, or use Systems Manager to do the patching for you.

Comment: Ok, I just need to create a snapshot of the current EBS volume to back it up? Yeah, I just need to change the instance type since it's too slow.

Comment: Yes, that will do okay as a backup!